# Working with size classes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, size-classes

I'm just starting to work with size classes. I've done my research and understand the concept but for the life of me cannot get the simplest of things to work. For example, an app I am practicing with will only work in portrait and I just want there to be a label thats centered and spans the width of the screen for all screen sizes, so I select the size class for all iPhones in portrait and set the label and constraints. The label looks great the 5.5in iPhone but anything smaller and the text gets cut off.[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of how your constrains looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be because the font size you set for the label is too big and will not fir in smaller screen sizes. For the label in the attribute inspector change  fonts minimum font scale to 0.5. Then try

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Actually I forgot to add leading and trailing constraints, along with you answer it fixed it! Thanks